# I'm using reverse geocoding in my application. why is it not working correctly everytime?

Tags: android, sms

For some of us, the correct location is displayed. but for many of us the location is not displayed. why is it so?  If worked correctly for few, then the code should be correct rite? why is it not working for others? Is it google's server problem?
Actually in reverse coding, is it like the geocoder class gets the latitude and longitude we got from geocoding program and returns the corresponding address of the lat and long matching with it in server?

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(ScreenActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                latitude = Double.toString(gps.getLatitude());
             longitude = Double.toString(gps.getLongitude());

                     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                     add= getMyLocationAddress(latitude,longitude);
                     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),add,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


            else

            {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }


        }

    });

    locationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            try {
             SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(AddContactsActivity.phno1, null,latitude+longitude+add, null, null);
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(AddContactsActivity.phno2, null,latitude+longitude+add, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ex.getMessage().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }

        }


    });
```

Comment: Help us to help you and post your code in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sources of error:

1. The location you send in your query is not exact. It is probably off by tens of meters.
2. The Reverse geocoding database is not of high quality. The service you are querying maintains a database of geographic locations to addresses. The quality of this data will basically determine how good the responses are.

If you want better answers, you have to improve both these things. Improving the database is expensive because you someone needs to move around and ground truth the data.

Basically, you should not expect reverse geocoding to give you perfect answers. If it gives you something close, things are working properly. The best you can probably do to improve your response is to improve the location accuracy.

Comment: atleast some thing close address is fine. but for few ppl it shows as cant get the address

Comment: If the service is returning a response, they probably don't have the address in the database. If it doesn't return a response at all, then you have a connection problem.

Comment: why cant they return atleast near by location?

Comment: That is something you need to ask the service provider. If you need something back, you can always try querying other nearby locations with different latitude and longitude values.

Comment: how to increase the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use only network location or device cannot found satellites.
Or some other application turns off location service or your application (e.g. some power optimization)